# ON_CALL does not work but EXPECT_CALL works

Tags: unit-testing, googlemock

I have a Unit test code where I have a mock to a function `foo`. When I use ON_CALL construct to specify the action, it does not perform my_action but just executes foo.

```
ON_CALL(my_mock, foo(my_matcher()))
.WillByDefault(DoAll(my_action(), Return(0)));
```

But when I do EXPECT_CALL, it works. In my case, foo() gets called only once. I tried to see how it could be different. But googling or searching stackoverflow didn't help. Below is the EXPECT_CALL that works:

```
EXPECT_CALL(my_mock, foo(my_matcher()))
.WillOnce(DoAll(my_action(), Return(0)));
```

I dont understand how they are different given the same my_matcher and my_action.

Answer (score 1):

`ON_CALL` provides a default action to run when an expectation is met. So an action defined in `ON_CALL` will not fire unless an expectation defined in `EXPECT_CALL` is fulfilled. The typical use case for `ON_CALL` is to replace a bunch of identical `WillOnce`/`WillRepeatedly` clauses in your `EXPECT_CALL`s. To make your snippet work, it will need to look like this:

```
ON_CALL(my_mock, foo(_))
  .WillByDefault(DoAll(my_action(), Return(0)));
EXPECT_CALL(my_mock, foo(my_matcher())).Times(1);
EXPECT_CALL(my_mock, foo(my_other_matcher())).Times(1);
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question is not answered. In both the cases, expectation is met, because I am running the same unittest with same inputs. How does ON_CALL does not cause my_action to be executed whereas EXPECT_CALL does?

Comment: As I said, the `ON_CALL` may only run when an expectation is fulfilled by a call. If you do not define `EXPECT_CALL`, there is nothing to fulfill.